# .htaccess: Transparently adding a name to the request

Tags: .htaccess

I've read this tutorial about how to modify your .htaccess in order to server many web2py applications but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dispatch\.fcgi/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.moublemouble.com [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =moublemouble.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /moublemouble/$1 [PT,L]
```

All I get is a 500 Internal Error and .htaccess is not my strong point. Any clues?

Comment: what tutorial did you read?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `RewriteCond` uses regular expressions that are matched against some string. You are trying to use some `x = y` syntax that is completely unsupported.

Thus your last three lines should look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.moublemouble.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^moublemouble.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /moublemouble/$1 [PT,L]
```

But please note that I only looked at the syntax and not the semantics of your rules.

Comment: I am getting 'RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters' on the error logs. Any other ideas?

Comment: With what syntax? Mine or yours?

Comment: I've removed the space between "NC," and "OR". The list of flags is comma-separated, not comma-space-separated.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error now but it doesn't do what it has to do